# How to ng serve an older Angular project?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, package.json

I'm trying to `ng serve` a sample Angular project included in a third party framework. The sample project is wanting Angular v~4 judging from its `package.json` file. My global CLI version is 6.0.8. The project doesn't include a `node_modules` folder nor an `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` file.

How can I successfully `ng serve` this older project?

Must I meddle with this project's `package.json` file to update the version numbers, or can I instead just install the older version ~4.0.3 of local Angular CLI?

And even then, once I install an older CLI version, how do I generate the `angular-cli.json` file via the CLI? So far I'm only able to get `node_modules` to appear - not an `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` file.

Comment: `ng new MyProjectName` generates a new Angular app with a basic angular.json that you could use

Comment: Try running `ng update @angular/cli` and see if that repairs the issue.

Comment: Projects (should) never include a `node_modules/` folder, that's what [`npm` and `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm) are for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue by running a different command: `npm run build`. This seemed to properly serve the app in its desired version.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what is the command behind `npm run build`. You could check that in the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a silly question but did you use `npm install` after getting the project to install the dependencies?

Only after that will appear the folder `node_modules`.

Comment: Very nice couldn't `ng serve` or `ng -v` in the app directory after a `git clone` but `npm install` in the app directory fixed evertyhing. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

In my case `npm run start` did the trick. Running *Angular 6* app while I just installed *Angular 8*.

In my `package.json` I have this behind the command.

```
...
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
      },
...
```