# Cannot open older Angular project with latest Angular version?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have just installed latest versions of Node.js (`v14.16.1`) and Angular (`11.2`).

Our TA gave us Angular project, but I cannot `ng sever`-it on my machine. I get following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'serve' target.
See "C:\Users\Miljan\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-hVo6jS\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

When I open the `angular-errors.log`, I have following output:

```
[error] Error: No projects support the 'serve' target.
at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Miljan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:58:19)
at async ServeCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Miljan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:127:9)
at async Object.runCommand (C:\Users\Miljan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:204:24)
at async default_1 (C:\Users\Miljan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:80:31)
```

Here you can [download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v3WuVwSSd1aGUc3RmuFS2W3xO5iDuSIq?usp=sharing) Angular project which TA gave us.

And bellow is `package.json` from TA's project:

```
{
      "name": "blog-client",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try installing and using the version of the CLI that the project dependencies require? Or just installing the project and using the scripts that will invoke that local version of the CLI? It shouldn't really be surprising that the latest CLI won't work with a v5 project.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to write a script that will invoke local version of the CLI. It would be great if you can give me a hint where to look for such a thing. For me as well is not surprising why CLI is complaining. Regarding your first question, I setup latest version of Ang so I can work with Tailwind, just by using ng add @ngneat/tailwind. I had problem setting up Tailwind with older versions of CLI and that's why I'm using latest version. Hope you can give me some useful tips. Cheers

Comment: Those scripts are already provided in the package file. If you want an up-to-date Angular project, use `ng new` with the up-to-date CLI instead of starting from an old one.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain precisely. Essentially, I have two project on my laptop. First one is the one I made (using ng new) for some other course (after installing latest Node and CLI),. Second one, is the one TA gave us. So the question is how to jump start older Angular project with latest CLI and Node? Do I have to lower-down the version of Angular CLI?

Comment: Then, again: use the scripts in the package file. Those will use the project's version of the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I managed it.

First `npm install`, `npm run-script build`, finally `ng serve`.

This helped [How to ng serve an older Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143390/how-to-ng-serve-an-older-angular-project)